# Using YQL how can I select an item from a feed that contains a colon in its name?

Tags: sql, rss, yql

I'm using YQL to parse some web feeds, this one in particular.

[SELECT * FROM rss WHERE url='http://www.arena.net/blog/feed'](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20rss%20WHERE%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arena.net%2Fblog%2Ffeed'&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)

This query returns a bunch of fields, one of which looks like

```
content:encoded
```

How can I select that field to filter? I want to do something like this,

```
SELECT title, link, pubDate, content:encoded FROM rss WHERE url='http://www.arena.net/blog/feed'
```

but that is invalid. I've tried escaping with a slash without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT title, link, pubDate, encoded
FROM rss
WHERE url='http://www.arena.net/blog/feed'
```

Here's a [console link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20title%2C%20link%2C%20pubDate%2C%20encoded%20FROM%20rss%20WHERE%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arena.net%2Fblog%2Ffeed%27).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. So is the first part ("content") just a namespace which is why it can be left off? 

The intricacies of XML are totally lost on me!

Comment: Yes, the `content` is a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Put the field name in *back-quotes*, of all things:

```
SELECT title, link, pubDate, `content:encoded` FROM rss
 WHERE url='http://www.arena.net/blog/feed'
```

Should work